# Undo php header redirect

Tags: php, redirect, header, undo

I am planting a [EAR](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Execution_After_Redirect_%28EAR%29) bug in a website. For that I want to undo the php header redirect that I performed. Example :-

```
if(!admin())
{
  header('Location: www.example.com/non-admin.php');
}

//Some code to undo the redirect happened above
```

By undoing the redirect happened above it would be EAR vulnerable. So is there any mechanism with which redirect can be undone?

Comment: [header_remove()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php)

Comment: Though you should also have an `exit` after your header redirect

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker. It worked :) This is an intentional bug that I am planting for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

See the `header_remove` function [documented on PHP.net](https://www.php.net/header_remove)

```
header_remove("Location");
```

If you are using PHP<5.3 you can also pass the `header` function a second parameter

```
header('Location: ', true);
```

[See doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Beware that headers are sent just before the first output. Check whether they were sent by calling `headers_sent()`